How can I pass a data from root layout to the all elements in the Next js app
I fetch localization from API. they are all basically an array containing objects with Keys and Values.
according to Next js, it is not possible to pass data from the layout to the child so I decided to go with this approach :

const _localization = (await post_req(process.env.LANG_GET_TRANSLATELIST,false,{AddLang: true,list:TranslationByPage},false)).data?.Data?.list;

   return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} ${yekan.variable} antialiased`}
      >
        <ConfigProvider _settings={_localization}>{children}</ConfigProvider>
      </body>
    </html>

but as you can see I have to use react context provider and it is a hook. so I have to make every component in my app client component to be able to use localization.
I created a hook as you can see:

export default function useLanguage(formKey) {
  const { _settings } = useContext(WAConfigContext);
  const _languages = _settings && _settings?.find((el) => Array.isArray(el));
  const _value = _languages && _languages.find((el) => el.FormKey === formKey);

  return _value?.Value || _value?.Key;
}


but I want to change that. it is just a one time data that I only fetch once and re validate it each 24 hours.
I want to be able to pass these localization without context provider so I won't need to make my components client component.
I wish there could be a way to have a prop all across my page.jsx files called languages for example. and I could filter them out with regular function instead of a hook.

if you want to pass the data from layout to whole application, you should try context api or redux store.

As per next.js docs: See link

If you are using fetch, requests are automatically memoized. This means you can safely call the same URL with the same options, and only one request will be made.

You can write a common function to call the API using fetch and call that function elsewhere
// utils.ts
export async function getSettings() {
  const res = await fetch(...);
  const settings = await res.json();
  return settings;
}

// layout.tsx
import { getSettings } from './utils';

export default async function PageLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const settings = await getSettings();
  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  );
}

// page.tsx
import { getSettings } from './utils';

export default async function HomePage() {
  const settings = await getSettings();
  return (
    <div>hello</div>
  );
}

